Invoking gradlew from script ends with 0% WAITING IDLE and blocks script
I'm trying to write a script that executes my gradle build multiple times with different targets to produce dependency output for all modules into individual files (that I can post process later). It's in a loop like this:
RESOURCES=$(pwd)"/../resources/projlist.txt"

while IFS="" read -r p || [[ -n "$p" ]]
do
  PROJ=$(printf '%s\n' "$p")
  echo "Collecting deps for $PROJ..."
  DEST=$(pwd)"/../resources/deps/$PROJ"
  pushd $GRADLEDIR
  $GRADLE --no-daemon "$PROJ:dependencies" # > $DEST
  popd
done < $RESOURCES

You will note that the intended redirect to file is commented. If uncommented it just hangs with no indication of why.  Commenting out the redirect to file shows this output at the end:
BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 28s
11 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 10 up-to-date
<-------------> 0% WAITING
> IDLE

This doesn't happen if the ./gradlew dependencies task is run outside of the script (no IDLE message).
(Please don't spend time talking about good/bad scripting practice here, unless it relates to solving the problem this is a quick hack together thing. )
I have tried --no-daemon and  modifying the project gradle.properties with:
org.gradle.daemon=false
org.gradle.daemon.idletimeout=1

I do note that it's claiming the Daemon will be stopped (but apparently isnt?). I see the following near the beginning of the script.
To honour the JVM settings for this build a single-use Daemon process will be forked. See https://docs.gradle.org/7.5.1/userguide/gradle_daemon.html#sec:disabling_the_daemon.
Daemon will be stopped at the end of the build 

I am unable to change the gradle version for this task. Gradle 7.5.1 is running under Java 11
I've tried both letting it run under zsh and with #!/usr/bin/env bash at the top.
Edit: I also ran status and see the following when the output has finished and the script is hanging:
 %  ./gradlew --status
   PID STATUS   INFO
 21027 STOPREQUESTED 7.5.1

How do I convince gradle to exit cleanly and let the script continue?

I don't know gradle, but could it be that gradle, if the stdout is not redirected to a file, accepts something on stdin to terminate it properly? As a first test, write the line as $GRADLE </dev/null ... >$DEST.
